# Does every drink bottle fit into every holder?

Tags: bottle

I have a Specalized drink bottle holder and was always using normal 750ml plastic bottles, but they never fit very well. I was looking online for water bottles and now I'm wondering if all bottles that can be found online (e.g. on bikester.com) will fit into my holder or do I have to be careful with what I buy? Are there different sizes of bottles and holders or all they standardized?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: From my observation over the years, there is no standard (as is the case with most things bicyclic). They're "supposed" to hold 73 mm bottles. But bottles aren't standard either.

Comment: plus all the "aero" bottles, and the oversize ones. But "standard" size is only  roughly standard IME

Comment: I've never seen a "standard" bike bottle (not one of those water bottles sold to girls in tights doing Tai Chi) that wouldn't fit a standard bottle "cage".  (There are, of course, some weird-shaped bike bottles which come with their own holders.)  I have seen some special cages designed to hold pop bottles instead of bike bottles, etc, but those should be labeled, if you study the descriptions.

Comment: Some holders (e.g. Topeak Modula line) are adjustable. I've used them to carry Camelbak Podium Bigchill bottles, coke bottles and coke cans without problems just by adjusting the size.

Answer (score 2):

The inexpensive bottle cages can be bent to make them a little smaller for a tighter fit. If the type you have is a closed  loop type you can add rubber bands to the bottle for a more secure fit if it is loose. There seems to be a lot more size variation with generic "sport bottles" than the bottles marketed to cyclists.